# Cuando un moderador convierte respuestas en comentarios ¿Puede responder el usuario nuevo?

Tags: soporte, privilegios, eliminación-de-respuestas

Al ser yo moderador, entre otras cosas, puedo convertir las respuestas en comentarios, cosa que algunas veces puede ser útil.

Muchas veces ocurre que un usuario nuevo hace una respuesta que debería ser un comentario, en parte porque no tiene el privilegio de [Comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Todos pasamos por esa parte, es bastante feo no tenerlo.

Si yo convierto la respuesta en comentario, y si alguno le responde, ¿El usuario nuevo puede responderle el comentario, al menos, solo en esa pregunta? ¿o por culpa de la falta del privilegio no puede?

No creo que algún usuario nuevo vea esto, por lo que hacer el experimento sería improbable o indebido. Lo mejor sería si otro moderador sabe la respuesta a esto, que la publique.

Comment: Haz la prueba aquí mismo. Convierte esto en comentario.

Comment: @Dolmenes Pero la cosa es para los usuarios de menos que 50 puntos de reputación, según el privilegio. De todos modos, ya estoy preparando una respuesta.

Comment: Ah, claro, que no pueden comentar. Lo que si te puedo decir es que no he sido notificado de la conversión. Tan solo me llego el comentario tuyo último.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es que hice el experimento, pero consultando con otros moderadores que hablan en otro idioma, *en una cueva de la que no me permiten hablar*, realmente pudimos encontrar la respuesta.

## No es posible que el usuario responda:

Lo que me dijeron fue algo como esto (con otras palabras):

> No puede responder, y además nos gustaría prohibir la edición de estos comentarios (no es obligatorio). La función *convertir en comentario* es para los usuarios que escribieron muy buenos comentarios, no para discusiones. Es posible convertir una respuesta en comentario junto con los comentarios que hay en ella, hacia la pregunta o hacia otra respuesta, pero solo si **contiene información útil**, en vez de debate.
>
> Por esto, también hay que evitar convertir las respuestas incompletas, ya que el autor de la pregunta no le podrá pedir aclaraciones ni por la edición de la pregunta, debido a la falta del privilegio.

---

#### Un buen dato a tener en cuenta

Según el comentario de @Dolmenes, al usuario que hizo la respuesta en forma de comentario, no le llega la notificación de que el comentario ha sido convertido.

> Dolmenes: No he sido notificado de la conversión. Tan solo me llegó el comentario tuyo último.